# Как скопировать первую строку скриптом?

Tags: android, shell

Как вы видите  скрипт  который сможет  копировать первую строку у файл1.тхт и вставлять ее в файл2 заменяя все содержимое файла2 ? И Вообще возможно ли это на android?
Так же интересует отдельный скрипт который бы смог удалить только первую строку у файла .

Answer (score 0):

Насчет андроида не скажу. Но в shell первая задача может решаться, например, вот так

```
head -n 1 file1.txt > file2.txt
```

Т.е. с помощью команды **head** получаем первую строку и результат перенаправляем в другой файл.

Варианты решения второй задачи зависят от того известно количество строк в файле или нет. Возможно хватит и **tail**

Comment: Нашел решение 
Копируем с помощью вашего  кода 
А удаляем с помощью Sed , спасибо !